# Cannot logout on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, components

I am not able to log out on button click and cannot work out why.
I have a logout button on my header.(navigation)

I am new to React.

I have a folder called Store, with Auth-context file, I have a login and logout handler in app.js,  I am importing AuthContext from ./store/auth-context.

I have no problems logging in, but I always have to do localStorage.clear() in the console to "logout".

In my Header component, I am calling as const isLoggedIn and onLogout with useContext(AuthContext).

On the bottom of the file in Header.js I have defined

```js
    {isLoggedIn && (BasicButton onClick={onLogout}>log out<BasicButton>)}
```

Since **onLogout** is storing the logoutHandler, I cannot work out why this will not execute when button is clicked. I am also using React Router version 6.4.4 
[Auth Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdqEj.png) 
[Handlers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvEQe.png)

Comment: Kindly add your code in the question only, instead of images

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to wrap child elements with AuthContext Provider

```js
// CONTEXT
const AuthContext = createContext()

const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) => {
   const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);
   
   const login = () => {
      setIsLogin(true)
   }

   const logout = () => {
      setIsLogin(false)
   }
   
   return (
     <AuthContext.Provider value={{isLogin, login, logout}}>
            {children}
     </AuthContext.Provider>
   )
}

export {AuthContext, AuthContextProvider}
```

You should wrap it with index.js provider

```
<AuthContextProvider>
  <App/>
</AuthContextProvider >
```

Now you can access isLogin, login and logout functions in the component you want using useContext

```js
const Navbar = () => {
   const {isLogin, login, logout} = useContext(AuthContext)
   ...
}
```